# How To run Opera version 38 through Webdriver (Selenium 2.53.1)?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, opera

I am using Opera version 38 and learning automation , I am unable to automate my code with my Opera browser.

```
        public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver d = new ChromeDriver();
    d.navigate().to("https://gmail.com");
}
```

This is the code for running in chrome but for opera am unable to get a driver (.exe file) from http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/ .

Comment: Share your code and HTML? and what error you are getting? please share everything.

Comment: It is straight forward, just download the driver from [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) and in the code use `IWebDriver driver = new OperaDriver(path of the driver);` I'm running on Opera as well.